# ¿Cómo hacer una migración a WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, migration, cms

En la empresa donde estoy trabajando tienen su sitio en Joomla y se quieren pasar a WordPress.

¿Como se puede hacer esa migración? es decir Trabajar el WP localmente (en PC) y luego hacer la migración? ó hacerlo desde un subdominio? y luego pasar todo al dominio raiz

En caso de que se haga desde un subdominio (que para mi es la mas lógica) ¿Como se haría esa migración del WP al dominio raíz?

GRACIAS

Comment: Saludos, considera leer [ask], la pregunta perece basada en opiniones y eso pudiera generar su cierre

Comment: Gracias ... ya cambie la pregunta

Comment: Wordpress trabaja con bases de datos, puedes montar todo donde quieras y cuando lo tengas listo lo subes al dominio definitivo. Si lo haces en local o en subdominio tiene poca importancia, aunque quizá para fines de prueba en local iría más rápido, pero quizá la configuración sea más pesada porque tendrías que instalar base de datos en local, etc. Si trabajas en subdominio ten cuidado de que Google no indexe ese contenido porque cuando lo subas al sitio definitivo podrías tener contenido duplicado y ser penalizado a nivel de SEO.